# Can I still < CopyProfile > without the /Generalize arg to the default Profile?

Tags: windows, windows-7, scripting, sysprep, waik

The title is self explanatory.  I had to remove the /generalize option when going from my sysprep to OOBE but that has now broken my copy profile.

I have read multiple places, that /generalize is needed for the copy profile and I cannot do this manually as the button to copy profile (in audit mode) is grayed out [to  copy the profile ]..

Can I still perform the  without the /Generalize when changing from my audit to OOBE?

If I need to script this - its okay.

Comment: Why did you have to remove /generalize in the first place ?

Comment: as the article suggest, you can also store the default profile on the network (netlogon on DC), if using a domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. According to [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973289), you MUST use the Generalize switch so that the Copy Profile parameter can be used. The note saying this is found under number 5. in the 'How to' section.

David
(for disclosure)
Windows Outreach Team - IT Pro

Comment: I can't even script this?

Comment: The only information I can give you on this is from [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2009/10/29/configuring-default-user-settings-full-update-for-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx). The article is a couple of years old, though. What you would be doing falls under the 'not supported' umbrella, so there is no official documentation.